# Wordpress Custom Fields. Display custom fields from user profile on a custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

On my wordpress blog I have the functionality that allows users who are logged in to be able to select categories of posts they would like to see as a stream on the blog page. So each user only sees posts from categories they have subscribed to and not all categories.

I used this code.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
?>
<h3>Extra profile information</h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="post_category">Display Categories</label><br />
            <span class="description">Which categories would you like to see posts from?</span>
        </th>
        <td>
            <ul class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php wp_terms_checklist( 0, array( 'checked_ontop' => false, 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'selected_cats' => get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'post_category', true ) ) ) ?>
            </ul>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php 
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

if( !isset( $_POST['post_category'] ) )
    return false;

if( !is_array( $_POST['post_category'] ) )
    return false;

 update_usermeta( $user_id, 'post_category', array_map( 'absint',
 $_POST['post_category'] ) );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_user_categories', 1000 );
function set_user_categories( $wp_obj ) {
if( !is_front_page() )
    return;

if( 'nav_menu_item' == $wp_obj->query_vars['post_type'] )
    return;

global $current_user;

$user_cats = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'post_category', true );
if( !$user_cats )
    return;

$wp_obj->set( 'category__in', $user_cats );
}
```

this is the result.

[image: How it looks for the user as they subscribe to their preferred categories]

This code works fine, however, I want these options to appear on another page and not the user profile, so I created another page template specifically for handling this.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Subscribe
*/
?>
<?php get_header() ?>

   <div class="page-container">
  <div><?php the_field('my_show_extra_profile_fields'); ?></div>
```

```
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

as you can see, I tried to display the field "my_show_extra_profile_fields" but it doesn't show up.

How can i make these options show on my page template subscribe.php and not the user profile??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. extra_field_name may be "post_category"

```
global $current_user;
echo get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'extra_field_name', true );
```

as like

```
echo get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'post_category', true );
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce @JakirHossain , i used that code you gave me, no luck. by the way. the first code i placed it in the functions.php and the second, i put it in my subscribe.php

Comment: This code use in your any template and need loged in user. my_show_extra_profile_fields is field name.

Comment: Its showing up! but the problem is its showing up on the edit page section which users do not have access to, i want those options to show up at the front end, not the back end  @JakirHossain

Comment: If answer is right, create my answer right and vote me.

Comment: I have Posted it in different templates and tried different themes, its not showing up on the front end for the users to interact with, only the back end edit options @JakirHossain it seems it got me half way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100336/discussion-between-jakir-hossain-and-drakata).